# Is there a Virtualization for gridview in windows store app?

Tags: windows, windows-phone-8.1, windows-8.1

Problem is faced, when we come across huge data items, where while scrolling the cells become black and glitches are seen throughout....any suggestion are appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not try IncrementalLoading to load your data in gridview.
[Tutorial](https://marcominerva.wordpress.com/2013/05/22/implementing-the-isupportincrementalloading-interface-in-a-window-store-app/)

Incase the link stops working
**Code Snippet**

```
public interface IIncrementalSource<T>
{
    Task<IEnumerable<T>> GetPagedItems(int pageIndex, int pageSize);
}

public class IncrementalLoadingCollection<T, I> : ObservableCollection<I>, 
     ISupportIncrementalLoading
     where T : IIncrementalSource<I>, new()
{
    private T source;
    private int itemsPerPage;
    private bool hasMoreItems;
    private int currentPage;

    public IncrementalLoadingCollection(int itemsPerPage = 20)
    {
        this.source = new T();
        this.itemsPerPage = itemsPerPage;
        this.hasMoreItems = true;
    }

    public bool HasMoreItems
    {
        get { return hasMoreItems; }
    }

    public IAsyncOperation<LoadMoreItemsResult> LoadMoreItemsAsync(uint count)
    {
        var dispatcher = Window.Current.Dispatcher;

        return Task.Run<LoadMoreItemsResult>(
            async () =>
            {
                uint resultCount = 0;
                var result = await source.GetPagedItems(currentPage++, itemsPerPage);

                if (result == null || result.Count() == 0)
                {
                    hasMoreItems = false;
                }
                else
                {
                    resultCount = (uint)result.Count();

                    await dispatcher.RunAsync(
                        CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal,
                        () =>
                        {
                            foreach (I item in result)
                                this.Add(item);
                        });
                }

                return new LoadMoreItemsResult() { Count = resultCount };

            }).AsAsyncOperation<LoadMoreItemsResult>();
    }
}
```